# Unable to call function in cgi-BashScript

Tags: bash, shell, cgi

I have a weird issue. When i run the script directly from command line it works fine. But when i execute it from Java Script the **remoteCall** function is not executed. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

SERVER="SERVER";
USERNAME="username";
THRESHOLD="70";     #   % Space occupied on disk. 
DF_COMMAND="df -Pkh";

function remoteCall() {
    echo "remote call "
    local RESULT;
    RESULT=$(ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $1);
    echo "$RESULT";
}

# Starting point for the script
function main() {
    echo "main function"
    local DF_Result=$(remoteCall "$DF_COMMAND");    # This function doesn't get called.
    echo "$DF_Result"
}

main
```

Java Script code calling the script is :

```
cgiUrl="cgi-bin/scanner.cgi";
function diskCheckingScript() {
    $.post(cgiUrl, function(result) {
    console.log("Result is",result);
    });
}
```

Comment: And the javascript code that calls it?

Comment: JavaScript code added in the questions.

Comment: Where do `$DF_COMMAND`, `$USERNAME`, and `$SERVER` get their values from?

Comment: These are variables declared in the script. Added in script.

Comment: How is this supposed to authenticate to the ssh server? If you're entering the password interactively, that won't work in a cgi script; if it's supposed to use a public key file in ~/.ssh, make sure that's available for the user account the cgi script runs under. Also, is there any reason to store output in a variable before printing it? For example, why not replace `RESULT=$(ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $1); echo "$RESULT"` with just `ssh $USERNAME@$SERVER $1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script may not be being executed with `bash` even though the header explicitly declares `#!/bin/bash`. A configuration in your CGI server may fix this, or perhaps making your script more conservative and compatible with the original `sh` (not just POSIX) shell would help:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

SERVER="SERVER"
USERNAME="username"
THRESHOLD="70"     #   % Space occupied on disk.
DF_COMMAND="df -Pkh"

remoteCall() {
    echo "remote call"
    RESULT=`ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1"`   # Perhaps we need to specify the full path of ssh. e.g. /usr/bin/ssh
    echo "$RESULT"
}

# Starting point for the script
main() {
    echo "main function"
    DF_Result=`remoteCall "$DF_COMMAND"`    # This function doesn't get called.
    echo "$DF_Result"
}

main
```

Note: We may not need to be to restrictive. POSIX may also be enough despite my favor on not basing from it completely.

```
    RESULT=$(ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1")   # Perhaps we need to specify the full path of ssh. e.g. /usr/bin/ssh

    DF_Result=$(remoteCall "$DF_COMMAND")    # This function doesn't get called.
```

You can also consider not calling the function with a subshell to get a result (very bad practice). Just use the variable that gets assigned anyway:

```
remoteCall() {
    echo "remote call"
    RC_RESULT=`ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1"`
}

# Starting point for the script
main() {
    echo "main function"
    remoteCall "$DF_COMMAND"    # This function doesn't get called.
    echo "$RC_RESULT"
}
```

Comment: I tried using your solution. But i am not able to use the single quotes you used for the function calling. Have you any idea how to deal with it.

Comment: @Amber Why not? You can also consider using `$()` again. Just don't use `local` and declare your function with `function`.

Comment: RESULT=`ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1"` is not getting executed. Else all is working fine.

Comment: @Amber Try specifying the complete path to `ssh` e.g. `/usr/bin/ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1"`. You can have it with `which ssh`.

Comment: Quotes and braces both are fine with Terminal. If i use single quotes then for JavaScript the `ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER" "$1"` is only a String. And when i am using braces the command ssh is not called from JavaScript.

Comment: If you can't use backquotes, just use `$()` format. Have you tried specifying full path of ssh?

Comment: I used the backquotes and gave the full path of ssh command. Still i was not able to execute the command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57048/discussion-between-amber-and-konsolebox).